# Show that the midpoints form a parallelogramm

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Let $\triangle ABC$ be a triangle with centroid $S$.

Show that :

(a) The midpoints of $\overline{AS}, \overline{BS}, \overline{BC}, \overline{AC}$ form a parallelogramm.

(b) If $\triangle ABC$ has two medians of the same length, then it is isosceles.

$$$$

For (a) :

Let $M_{AS}, M_{BS}, M_{BC}, M_{AC}$ the midpoints.

Then we have to show that $M_{AS}M_{AC}=M_{BS}M_{BC}$ and that $M_{AS}M_{AC} \parallel M_{BS}M_{BC}$, right?

For that do we have to consider similar triangles?

Answer (score 1):

All you have to use that red segments are parallel and that bigger is twice as smaller (because of similarity of triangles $ABC$ and $ADE$). [image]

Comment: These two triangles are equal because they have the same angle at $A$ and since $D$ and $E$ are the midpoints of the sides $AB$ and $AC$ respectively and so we get that $\frac{AD}{AB}=\frac{AE}{AC}$, right? And since $\frac{AD}{AB}=\frac{AE}{AC}$ it follows that $DE\parallel BC$, right? Does it hold that $DE=\frac{1}{2}\cdot BC$ because $D$ and $E$ are midpoints?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: I got stuck right now. Is the midpoint of $AS$ on $DE$ ?

Comment: So do we have to prove that first?

Comment: I see you give rarely a credit to people help  you?